# Access Query: Subtract last 2 values, specific to ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

Help appreciated! My table is setup as follows:
*fake data* TableName = GAD7

```
[PatientID   Date        Value
Sam        10/21/2022    15
George     06/12/2022     7
Luke       09/03/2021    11
Sam        05/15/2020    20 
George    12/02/2017      2
George    01/01/1992      6][1]
```

So I have potentially multiple rows of the same patient, w/different dates.
I need to create a query that subtracts the LAST 2/most recent values for each patient.
So my query would show only those with 2+ records. Negative values are fine/expected.
My successful query would then show:

```
PatientID (LastScore - 2nd_toLastScore)
Sam        -5.0 
George     5.0
```

*Luke is not shown because he only has one value*

I was able to formulate a query to show only those PatientIDs with >= 2 records and last date and last value. I am not sure how to get the second from last date/value AND THEN subtract those values.

[Access query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgbAj.png)

The SQL view :

```sql
SELECT GAD7.PatientID, Count(GAD7.PatientID) AS CountOfPatientID, Last(GAD7.TestDate) AS LastDate, Last(GAD7.Score) AS LastScore
FROM GAD7
GROUP BY GAD7.PatientID
HAVING (((Count(GAD7.PatientID))>=2))
ORDER BY GAD7.PatientID;
```

Comment: Signs are bacwards according to description of calculation. "7 from 2" would be -5 and "15 from 20" would be 5.

Comment: Does table have a unique identifier field such as autonumber? As listed, seems odd that George's last record has a date earlier than second record.

Comment: Edited for clarity/accuracy. The table currently does not have an autonumber but I can make it have one if that would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

Query1: Score1

```
SELECT GAD7.*
FROM GAD7
WHERE 1=(SELECT Count(*)+1 FROM GAD7 AS G7 
         WHERE G7.PatientID=GAD7.PatientID AND G7.TestDate>GAD7.TestDate);
```

Query2: Score2

```
SELECT GAD7.*
FROM GAD7
WHERE 2=(SELECT Count(*)+1 FROM GAD7 AS G7 
         WHERE G7.PatientID=GAD7.PatientID AND G7.TestDate>GAD7.TestDate);
```

Query3:

```
SELECT Score2.PatientID, [Score2].[Score]-[Score1].[Score] AS D
FROM Score1 INNER JOIN Score2 ON Score1.PatientID = Score2.PatientID;
```

Could nest the SQL statements for an all-in-one query.

Or this all-in-one version using TOP N to pull previous Score:

```
SELECT GAD7.*, (SELECT TOP 1 Score FROM GAD7 AS Dupe 
                WHERE Dupe.PatientID = GAD7.PatientID AND Dupe.TestDate<GAD7.TestDate 
                ORDER BY Dupe.TestDate DESC) AS PrevScore 
FROM GAD7 WHERE PatientID IN
    (SELECT PatientID FROM GAD7 GROUP BY PatientID HAVING Count(*)>1) 
AND 1=(SELECT Count(*)+1 FROM GAD7 AS G7 WHERE G7.PatientID=GAD7.PatientID AND G7.TestDate>GAD7.TestDate);
```

Comment: June7. Just brilliant.  If I wanted to limit Query1:Score1 to particular dates (9/1/2021-8/31/2022) ... with subsequent queries based off that.... where would I add that to the SQL code?  (newbie way over my head with a project)

Comment: oi. I think I got it! just built a 4th query with a relationship bw my original query and your 3rd query. THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!!!